# How to retrieve a GridCheckBox column value through webform codebehind

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a telerik RadGrid that is being populated via a ObjectDataSouce. This object returns a series of boolean fields

```
<telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsSysAdmin" DataType="System.Boolean"FilterControlAltText="Filter IsSysAdmin column" HeaderText="Sys Admin"
 SortExpression="IsSysAdmin" UniqueName="IsSysAdmin">
```

Once I select a column I would like to be able to derive the boolean value for use in another section of the page.

I can get at the values in the selected rows by doing the following:

```
  protected void gv_roleList_Command(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "EditItem")
            {
              GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
              item.Selected = true;
              txt_RoleName.Text = item["RoleName"].Text;
```

...edited for brevity

By calling the column I can get the values however this does not work for a GridCheckBoxColumn the text attribute only returns   (which I would expect).

I have tired to cast the sender as checkbox to go at it that way but my implementation does not seem to work.

```
var cb = (GridCheckBoxColumn)sender;
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to go about deriving the value from the Checkbox column?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code snippet.

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName ==  "EditItem")
    {
        // if current row is in normal mode
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        CheckBox chk = item["IsSysAdmin"].Controls[0] as CheckBox;

        // If your row is in edit mode
        GridEditableItem eitem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        CheckBox echk = eitem["IsSysAdmin"].Controls[0] as CheckBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that works perfectly I also found a similar article within the telerik forums for any interested http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/checkbox-value.aspx